# variable i behavioiur in switch case

Tags: c, switch-statement, storage-class-specifier

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    int i=9;
    switch(i)
    {
         static int i=1;
         i=3;
         i=i*i;

         case 3:
                 i=i+11;
         case 4:
                 i=i+22;
         case 5:
                 i=i+33;
         default:
                 i=i+44;
          printf("%d",i);
    }
    printf("%d",i);
}
```

I doesn't understand the actual behavioiur, the output is **45 9**. 
Could any one give me valid reason.

1. How it  works?
2. why it is?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe the `switch` is just jumping to the `default` case (since `i` is 9). This means the `static i` is only initialized to 1, but the previous statements that change it are jumped over and skipped. Thus, in the default case, `i` is 1. Add 44 to it and print it results in `45`. The `9` is printed because the `static i` is out of scope, and thus uses the other `i` that is storing the value 9.

Comment: if switch is jumped direct case 9/default action, how could the switch knows there is  a static declaration in scope of switch block @Cornstalks

Comment: @aaripakaprashad Because static variables are initialized prior to program startup.

Comment: You can also jump across other (non-static) declarations (no matter if that jump is caused by `switch`, `goto`, or whatever). If the identifier is visible in the current scope, you can refer to it. (If the inner `i` in the example wasn't static, the initialization would be skipped, leaving `i` uninitialized, but the denoted object would exist through the entire block where it's declared. And for completeness' sake: VLA declarations are an exception, they cannot be skipped.)

Answer (score 4):

No statements before `case:` is executed inside switch except for `variable declaration`

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    int i=9;
    switch(i)
    {
         static int i=1;
         printf("I AM HERE %d\n", i);
         i=3;
         i=i*i;

         case 3:
                 i=i+11;
         case 4:
                 i=i+22;
         case 5:
                 i=i+33;
         default:
                 i=i+44;
          printf("%d",i);
    }
    printf("%d",i);
}
```

The output **would not** print the string `I AM HERE`.

This switch is similar to writing as

```
    switch(i)
    {
         static int i=1;
         case 3:
                 i=i+11;
         case 4:
                 i=i+22;
         case 5:
                 i=i+33;
         default:
                 i=i+44;
          printf("%d",i);
    }
```

Since the value of `i = 9`, the `default` case is executed, which prints `i = 45`.

Also the scope of the variable `i` declared inside switch is limited only inside `switch {}` block. So once the control comes out of this scope the value of `i = 9` which is declared in the block of `main`

Answer (score 1):

You have two `i`s... one visible only in the block that makes up the `switch()` body, and the other outside it.  The `switch(i)` switches on the outer `i` (the one initialized to 9), so it goes to the `default:` case.  When it then runs the following code under `default:`:

```
     default:
             i=i+44;
      printf("%d",i);
```

...it is using the `i` declared inside the `switch()` block (the one initialized to `1`), so it prints "45".  This doesn't affect the `i` outside the switch, though.

After the `switch()` block's closing brace, the second `printf()`:

```
   }
   printf("%d",i);
```

uses the `i` from outside the switch (the one initialized to 9), so it prints "9".

Essentially, the `switch()` body is a block, and a variable declared in a block is local to that block -- but can hide another variable with the same name from an outer scope.

Answer (score 0):

The switch statement works as follows:

1. The switch statement evaluates the expression in parentheses (in this case, `i` with a value of `9`) and jumps to the appropriate `case` (which in this case is `default`, since no `case 9` exists).
2. Variables before the first `case` are declared. In this case, a new variable named `i` is declared with the value `1`. *Note that while this shares name with the previously declared `i`, they are separate variables and the new variable "overrides" the previous until the end of the switch statement.* Since we jump directly to the `default` label, none of the code before this label is run.
3. The code runs until either it encounters a `break` or the end of the switch statement. Then all variables declared inside the switch statement disappear, and in our case, the old `i` variable is again accessible.

At the `default` label, the program adds 44 to the "new" `i` variable (which previously was `1`) and adds 44 to it, giving it the new value 45. It then prints the value.

After the switch statement, however, the new `i` variable has been unloaded and the old `i` variable becomes accessible again. It still has the old value of `9`, so that is the value that is printed.